# Google Cloud Platform VM/Compute Engine down without notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

As shown in the picture linked/attached, my VM was down late June 7 (marked by the 3 vertical purple line), without any notification that it's down. In fact, when I went to my VM instances to check it, it was displayed as still running, but I could not access it through SSH.
Any ideas is appreciated! I am also curious why the CPU still has activity after it was down.

[screenshot of monitoring dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYtgs.png)

Comment: CPU at 100%, Memory near 100%. What does that tell you?

Comment: I do see that. I think CPU is okay, since there are two vCPU, so the max is at 200% actually. Do you think it's because of high utilization of memory? The max of memory utilization was 86%. I don't want to push the limit close to 100%. That's why I set a threshold for warning at 95%. But 86% is not too too bad to me.. maybe it is for GCP?

Comment: Your VM is hung or in a loop locking up the CPU. That is what those numbers indicate. Two CPUs do not mean 200% available.

Comment: The reason I thought that way about CPU utilization % is because there were periods that the CPU utilization went to ~160% and the VM had no interruption. I think you are right. But I don't know why VM did not break in those incidents.

Comment: If your VM CPU usage is over 80% you have a problem to solve. Some VMs permit overutilization for short bursts, some do not.